# For loop: calculate the lag difference per group

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, group-by, lag

I have a large dataframe in which I would like to calculate the lag difference per ID for multiple columns.

This is an example of what i like to obtain, and what I obtain

[image: Example]

I do not understand why it does not work and hope someone can help me.

Here is the code for the making the dataframe I use as example:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=200,ncol=2))
x <- c("id","age")
colnames(df) <- x

df$id <- sample(1001:1200)
df$age <- ceiling(rnorm(200,mean=70,sd=15)) 

new_df <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  new_row <- df[i,]
  new_row <- transform(new_row[rep(nrow(new_row), each=20),], age = age + seq(20))
  new_df <-rbind(new_df,new_row)
  
}

numMeds <- 20
for (i in 1:numMeds) {
  med <- sample(0:1,4000, replace=TRUE)
  new_df[ , paste0("Med ",i)]   <- med
  
}
```

I used the following code which works for one column:

```
df<-new_df%>%
group_by(id)%>%
mutate(newMed1=(Med1 - lag(Med1)))
```

I tried a loop for multiple columns but it does not group the function per ID.

[image: example of result from my code]

Code:

```
List<-df%>%
select(-c(1,2)
list.meds<-colnames(List)

df2<-df%>%
group_by(ID)

for(i in list.meds){
df2[,paste0("new,i)] <- df2[[i]] - lag(df2[[i]]
}
```

Comment: Check out the [`dplyr::across`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html) function. You can try `new_df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~.x - lag(.x), names = "new{.col}"))`

Comment: Thanks! for people searching having the same problem: I did need to use "." before names:  .names="new{.col}"